# Is there a way to "prime" tesseract or other OCR engines for certain words

Tags: computer-vision, tesseract, omr

Is there a way to prime Tesseract-OCR or perhaps another engine to have increased sensitivity to certain words/shapes? [Priming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) is a way that humans can increase their sensitivity towards certain stimuli, I wasn't sure if OCR does the same thing.  I know apps like facebook/instagram can increase sensitivity towards certain posts or behaviors towards certain accounts if the account has exhibited that behavior in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **user-words** file is a bit finicky to get working.

Here's a reduced version of the code I used to get it working

```cpp
#include <tesseract/genericvector.h>
.
.
.
    const char* TESSDATA = "C:/Tesseract/tessdata/";

void TryTess() {
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();


    GenericVector<STRING> pars_vec;
    pars_vec.push_back("load_system_dawg");
    pars_vec.push_back("load_freq_dawg");
    pars_vec.push_back("load_punc_dawg");
    pars_vec.push_back("load_number_dawg");
    pars_vec.push_back("load_unambig_dawg");
    pars_vec.push_back("load_bigram_dawg");
    //pars_vec.push_back("load_fixed_length_dawgs");
    pars_vec.push_back("language_model_penalty_non_dict_word");
    pars_vec.push_back("user_words_suffix");
    pars_vec.push_back("user_patterns_suffix");


    GenericVector<STRING> pars_values;
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    pars_values.push_back("0");
    //pars_values.push_back("F");
    pars_values.push_back("9999999999999999");
    pars_values.push_back("user-words");
    pars_values.push_back("user-patterns");

    api->Init(TESSDATA, "eng", OEM_DEFAULT, NULL, 0, &pars_vec, &pars_values, false);

    /// Some image preprocessing to improve detection

    char* out = api->GetUTF8Text();
    std::cout << "Result: " << out;
    api->End();
    delete[] out;
}
```

Make sure you have your TESSDATA path configured.  The best few resources I could find were [Here](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version)
as well as [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample).

The major hangup was not knowing where that genericvector.h class was, as tesseract's Init method requires that class (there doesn't seem to be any conversion methods). Since the **user-words** file must be passed in prior to initialization, this is the only way I could find to do it.  Even reading from a config file must be done after initialization, which prevents you from using **user-words**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Users used to be able to specify a `user-words` file, but the feature seems to be not working in latest versions of Tesseract, except maybe in legacy mode.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/960

Comment: I actually managed to get it working myself! I have no idea how to share my results